# VBS script for opening text file and taking select parts and putting them into excel

Tags: excel, text, vbscript

For example I will have this line in the text file:
 RTL      N23 U 194.0    |        SYSTEM   N24 U 978.9 744.3     | etc

I want to copy the value until the "|" then insert into an excel file.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest open Excel, enable developer tools and use macro recording to record those steps you want.

After that, stop recording and you'll end up with the basics of your vbscript.

Hereafter you'll need some adjusting of the code, which I can surely help you with.

Comment: This is a text file so it will be hard to manipulate it in excel. I only need certain values to be inserted into the excel cells from the text file.

Comment: post a piece of this text file, and I can give you a start.

Comment: RTL      N23 U 194.0                 |                                          SYSTEM   N24 U 978.9 744.3           |                                          ADA      N24 U 109.0 108.9           |                                          ADB      N24 U 107.4 107.5

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this should get you started.

Note that I named the file data.txt where the data resides in.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\Temp\data.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```